# Collapse all sections in accordion on page load in jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery Accordion, I want to hide all the sections on page load. Only when user clicks on header that section should open.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use this in your document ready function when initialising the accordion:

```
$("#someid").accordion({collapsible : true, active : 'none'});
```

Comment: THANKS!...just a note for n00bs like myself, just add to the current accordion tag like so: $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible : true, active : 'none' });

Answer (score 22):

**active : 'none'** is an invalid value, it may appear to work on the surface, but will break other aspects of the accordion widget.  Use this instead:

```
$("#someid").accordion({collapsible : true, active : false});
```

Comment: API Documentation regarding `active` option : http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. However it you're looping through a list (in my case its MVC grouped By list) make sure the collapse class is outside of the loop to speed it up substantially.

```
$('.collapse').parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus")
     .addClass("glyphicon-plus").css('color', 'green');

$('.collapse').collapse('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

By url parameters you can expand specific tab or collapse all,
for collapsing all use:

```
 $("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active' , 'null');
```

for expanding specific use:

```
$("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active' , <?php if($_GET['tab']!='')echo $_GET['tab'];else echo 'null'; ?>);
```