# jquery accordion collapsed by default on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI accordion in my page. I have following Javascript code on my page load:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
            active: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            navigation: true,
            collapsible: true
        });

});
```

When the page loads all tabs are open for few seconds and then collapse. May be its loading effect. How can I make Jquery UI accordion collapsed on page load. Please suggest

Comment: Could you reproduce this on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Andrew: Please check the link. http://jsfiddle.net/47aSC/    sorry I used it for the first time and its not formatted. I guess jquery links need to be from live site.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633971/how-do-i-keep-jquery-ui-accordion-collapsed-by-default

Comment: @Mrchief: I am already using active false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapse all sections in accordian on page load in jQuery Accordian](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675263/collapse-all-sections-in-accordian-on-page-load-in-jquery-accordian)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although not a direct answer, maybe you can render it hidden and then show it when its created:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
   active: false,            
   autoHeight: false,            
   navigation: true,            
   collapsible: true,
   create: function(event, ui) { $("#accordion").show(); }
});
```

**Update:** This fiddle works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/47aSC/6/

Comment: @mootinator @Merchief: I used display none and used your code samples (both) but when page loads then accordion is invisible and appears suddenly. I want accordion to be there but collapsed when page loads

Comment: Well, according to the documentation, having `{active: false, collapsible: true}` should render everything collapsed. I wonder if something else is interfering. Can you create a jsfiddle with your issue?

Comment: . jsfiddle.net/47aSC sorry I used it for the first time and its not formatted. I guess jquery links need to be from live site.    I am using this in asp.net content page. may be thats the reason ?

Comment: Check your jQuery.js and jQuery UI js version. Maybe you're using an old and buggy version?

Comment: Edited your fiddle to use latest libraries. Can you update with your css too? http://jsfiddle.net/47aSC/1/

Comment: Added themes too: http://jsfiddle.net/47aSC/5/. I can see everything collapsed by default.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.5.1.min  and jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min

Comment: and css like this: jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css

Answer (score 9):

For me this works:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            active: false

        });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably loading something near the end of the page slowly.  If you can't fix that, you could try declaring the element having `display:none` applied to it in css, then:

```
$("#accordion").show().accordion({
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        collapsible: true
    });
```

There could be a cleaner way of doing that (as @Mrchief suggests), but I don't think `.accordion()` formats hidden elements nicely.  You'll have to test.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is:

open jquery.ui.accordion.js and edit lines 29 and 31 (by the way I'm using 1.10.4).

Edit line 29 to **Active: 100,**
Edit line 31 to **collapsible: true,**

This way you don't need to write any script or function in the header of the page. By setting **Active** to a high number (for example 100) you are saying that 100th h3 tag is active (which basically doesn't exist).

The **collapsible**: true says that all open h3 tags are collapsible.

It solves the problem completely.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.collapse').collapse({
     toggle: false
   });
});
```

This will set all `.collapse` classes in DOM to close, but only once the DOM has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

**//  We can also use the below code to collapse accordian on the page load and it should use when we are using bootstrap 2.0**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          if ($("#accordianId").length>0) {
                        $("#accordianId").trigger("click");
                    }
             });
```

**Other wise we should use below code for bootstrap 3.0**

```
$( "#accordianId" ).accordion( "option", "active", 0 );
```