# How do I keep my accordion collapsed on page load?

Tags: jquery, accordion

How can I get my accordion script to be closed when the page loads? My script is this:

```
$('[data-fn="accordion"]').on('click',function(e) {
     var id = $(this).data('open');
 $('#'+id).slideToggle();
   if(!$(this).children('.icon-arrow').hasClass('open')) {
 $(this)
 .children('.icon-arrow')
 .addClass('open')
 .removeClass('close');
 e.preventDefault();
}
 else {
 $(this)
   .children('.icon-arrow')
   .removeClass('open')
   .addClass('close');
  e.preventDefault();
}
  });
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thokoch/NxLpq/)

Thanks,
regards Thomas

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575610/jquery-accordion-collapsed-by-default-on-page-load

Comment: I did have a look at that, but then i have to redo all my css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Have a look at the updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/NxLpq/2/

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
        collapsible: true
    });

});

$('[data-fn="accordion"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).data('open');
    $('#' + id).slideToggle();
    if (!$(this).children('.icon-arrow').hasClass('open')) {
        $(this)
            .children('.icon-arrow')
            .addClass('open')
            .removeClass('close');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(this)
            .children('.icon-arrow')
            .removeClass('open')
            .addClass('close');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Some CSS ajustment and all was working :)

Comment: Glad to have helped ;)