# Close all Accordion Section When Page Loads

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using JQuery Accordian, I want to hide all the sections on page load. Only when user clicks on header that section should open. Can any one help me out..

$(document).ready(function()
{

```
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });


$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');


$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
    if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
        $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }

    else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }
});

return false;
```

});

HElp.. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate to this [Google Hurts???]
[Check it first][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575610/jquery-accordion-collapsed-by-default-on-page-load

Answer (score 0):

```js
  Add this to your jQuery
  **jQuery('.panel-collapse').removeClass("in");**
  This will close the accordion on page load
```

```html
  
`<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne"> 
    <div class="panel-body">   
      <div class="textwidget">
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [.collapse('hide')](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#yourAccordionId').collapse("hide");

     // Rest of the code here

});
```