# jQuery UI - Accordion - hover on active item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        // heightStyle: "fill",
        collapsible: true,
        active: 0,
        animate: "swing",
        event: "mouseenter"
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function () {
         $(this).accordion("option", "active", false);
     });

  });
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>First header</h3>
  <div>First content panel</div>
  <h3>Second header</h3>
  <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using jQuery UI with an accordion where the content is shown if I hover the "title".

The problem here when I hover an **already "active"** item it will be deactivated. Here is a [PEN](https://codepen.io/larz/pen/NYrgBy)

JS:

```
$("nav").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: 0,
    animate: "swing",
    event: "mouseenter"
})
```

Comment: Using hover to show/hide content is generally a bad idea, because it doesn't take touchscreen devices (small and large) into account. Use click events instead.

Comment: As per - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675263/collapse-all-sections-in-accordian-on-page-load-in-jquery-accordian - if you change active to none - `active: 'none',` is that the behavior you want Not starting with the first one active?

Comment: @DaveCoast no, I mean when you hover an activated item-title again it will be deactivated. I want when I hover an activated item again it should be still activated.